# How to convert all int dtypes to double simultanously on PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, double

here's my `dataset`

```
DataFrame[column1: double, column2: double, column3: int, column4: int, column5: int, ... , column300: int]
```

What I want is

```
DataFrame[column1: double, column2: double, column3: double, column4: double, column5: double, ... , column300: double]
```

What I did
`dataset.withColumn("column3", datalabel.column3.cast(DoubleType()))`

It is too manual, can you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to construct the converted field list.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
...
cols = [F.col(field[0]).cast('double') if field[1] == 'int' else F.col(field[0]) for field in df.dtypes]
df = df.select(cols)
df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 2):

You first need to filter out your `int` column types from your available schema.

Then in conjunction with [reduce](https://realpython.com/python-reduce-function/) you can iterate through the `DataFrame` to cast them to your choice

`reduce` is a very important & useful functionality that can be utilise to navigate any iterative use case(s) within Spark in general

### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'id':[f'id{i}' for i in range(0,10)],
        'col1': [i for i in range(80,90)],
        'col2': [i for i in range(5,15)],
        'col3': [6,7,5,3,4,2,9,12,4,10]
    
})


sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: long (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: long (nullable = true)
```

### Identification

```
sparkDF.dtypes

## [('id', 'string'), ('col1', 'bigint'), ('col2', 'bigint'), ('col3', 'bigint')]

long_double_list = [ col for col,dtyp in sparkDF.dtypes if dtyp == 'bigint' ]

long_double_list

## ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

### Reduce

```
sparkDF = reduce(lambda df,c: df.withColumn(c,F.col(c).cast(DoubleType()))
                ,long_double_list
                ,sparkDF
            )

sparkDF.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

VectorAssembler converts integer values to floating point values in multiple columns. You can separate a vector column into columns and rename the columns as below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.functions import vector_to_array
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Create an input DataFrame
N_COLUMNS = 3
pdf_int = pd.DataFrame(
    data={f"column{x}": [x, x*2] for x in range(1, N_COLUMNS+1)},
    dtype=np.int64)
pdf_double = pd.DataFrame(
    data={f"column{x}": [x+0.5, x*2+0.5] for x in range(N_COLUMNS+1, N_COLUMNS*2+1)},
    dtype=np.float64)
pdf_input = pd.concat([pdf_int, pdf_double], axis=1)

df_input = spark.createDataFrame(pdf_input)
col_names = df_input.columns
df_input.show()

# Convert all integer columns to double and leave double values unchanged
df_output = VectorAssembler().setInputCols(col_names).setOutputCol("vector"). \
    transform(df_input).select("vector").\
    withColumn("array", vector_to_array("vector")).select("array"). \
    select([col("array")[i] for i in range(len(col_names))]). \
    toDF(*col_names)
df_output.show()
print(type(df_output))

# Verify all values are equal except types between the input and output
pdf_output = df_output.toPandas()
assert pdf_input.astype("float64").equals(pdf_output)
assert df_input.schema != df_output.schema
```